# list items per property (here date) in the list view

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

i have a simple extbase extension with a model "item".
Each item has a title, a description and a date.

How can i list my items according to the date?

e.G.

24.06.17:
item 2
item 6
item 7

25.06.14:
item 1

...

i search the logic to realize this (in the view or in the controller)

Comment: Do you want to list the items in the TYPO3 frontend sorted by the date field?

Comment: Yes. I want to make it similar to an A-Z list.

First, there comes a headline "A", the all items with A are listed.
And so on.

The same with the date instead of the Char.
The first headline is the first existing date.. 

The question is:
Must i get make a new Array in my Controller:
DateWithItems with two keys: date and items

or can i make it in the view?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can sort your record by date.
In fluid you can use the vhs viewhelpers set:

```
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/SetViewHelper.html
```

Something likes (I don't test it):

```
<f:for each="items" as="item">
  <f:if condition="{item.date}=={current}">
    <f:then>
      {item.title}
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      <br/>{item.date}: {item.title}
    </f:else>
  </f:if>
  <v:variable.set name="current" value="{item.date}" />
</f:for>
```

Comment: i need a headline with the date and then all items which belong to this date

Comment: i tried using the groupedFor viewhelper:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753015/typo3-groupedfor-viewhelper-according-to-dates

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vhs viewhelpers` like below.

```
<f:for each="{dataset -> vhs:iterator.sort(sortBy: 'date')}" as="item">
    .........
    .........
</f:for>
```